# Angular 5 page reload

Tags: angular, navigation, reload

Could someone hellps me? I Use Angular 5. When I navigate to some route like `this.router.navigate(['somePath']);` my url in browser changed to `basicUrl/somePath`. Everything is ok until page reload in browser. After it I see my component (no navbar and other things, only my component html). How can I improve this behaviour? Now I have in every my component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.location.replaceState('/');
}
```

to replace browser url. But I do not like this solution.

Comment: Have a look at `HashLocationStrategy`

Comment: pls post your main routing file.

Answer (score 0):

You should navigate relatively :

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
this.router.navigate(['somePath', ], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
```

Answer (score 0):

window.location.reload in button click event

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button color="warn" onclick="window.location.reload();">
```